# MySQL при вставки строки #1442 - Can't update …

Tags: mysql

Доброе время суток.
Вот БД, таблицы научился создавать, со строками тоже могу работать.
Вот решил попробывать создать простенький триггер (отрабатывающий после вставки)

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `NewRecord` AFTER INSERT ON `operator` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE `operator` SET `Export` =1;
END
```

Так при добавлении записи в таблицу, валится ошибка: *«#1442 - Can't update table 'operator' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger»*
Решение которой описывается в «[статье](http://ru-mysql.livejournal.com/254557.html)»
Но у меня как-то не получается с ней справиться.

Разъясните пожалуйста, где собака зарыта …
Заранее спасибо

P.S.
Client API version: mysqlnd **5.0.10** - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно. Если вы уже вставили запись, то логично, что менять уже что-то поздно. Триггер после записи обычно нужен для изменения (расчета) каких-то данных в других таблицах: в статье приведен пример, где по добавлению лайка в таблицу лайков меняется общее количество лайков в другой таблице.
Если вам нужно поменять запись, которая вставляется, делайте это в BEFORE INSERT и там уже `set new.export = 1` сработает.

Comment: Да, **получилось**.  
А я думал тут как в "Interbase" и "FireBird" - можно значения записи менять, после добавления самой записи

Comment: Можно еще вопрос на эту тему, сделал все как в примере:<br/>

    `CREATE TRIGGER `UpdRecord` BEFORE UPDATE ON `operator`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
  if (OLD.`export` = 0) then 
  UPDATE operator SET NEW.`export` = 2;
  end if;
end`

на редактировании записи, в которой 'Export=0', точно такая же ошибка

Comment: с учетом http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_update.php и http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php я вообще получается не могу обновить старое значение?

Comment: Обратите внимание в статье на то, что в before insert(update) обновляется не таблица, а поля записи NEW. Обновлять всю таблицу не нужно, вы находитесь уже в контексте обновления записей. Поэтому не `UPDATE operator SET NEW.export = 2;` а просто `SET NEW.export = 2;`

Comment: > You can update the NEW values.

Comment: все, разобрался, **спасибо** :-), 
begin if (OLD.export = 0) then SET NEW.export = 2; end if; end

Answer (score 1):

Там же приведен правильный пример.

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `NewRecord` AFTER INSERT ON `operator` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SET NEW.Export=1;
END
```

писать запрос целиком к той же таблице нельзя. Поскольку он в свою очередь вызовет выполнение триггера - и так далее. Поэтому и существует специальный синтаксис, который и описан в той статье. просто сначала там дается пример неправильного синтаксиса, а ниже - "в конечном счёте правильный вариант".
Я согласен, что там написано не очень внятно, но если читать внимательно и до конца, то все становится на свои места.

Не обратил внимание, что это AFTER INSERT. MEW работает с BEFORE.

А вообще, конечно, нужен конкретный реальный пример, а не искусственный.

Comment: Я извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но я хотел имменно "**AfterInsert**",
по вашему ответу, я изменил содержание триггера и при его сохранении получил:
     
         "*The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `NewRecord` AFTER INSERT ON `operator` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET NEW.Export=1; END"
MySQL said: #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger*"